# Qt Installer Create Start Menu Shortcut

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I'm fighting with Qt Installer Framework for creating a shortcut for my application into start menu in Windows Platform.
I used the same script as into startmenu example, but it throws an error during the creation of the shortcut. I don't understand the reason it looks there is a problem with path in my code:

```
Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    // call default implementation to actually install README.txt!
    component.createOperations();
    if (systemInfo.productType === "windows") {
        component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/EurocontrolGui.exe", "@StartMenuDir@/EurocontrolGui.lnk",
            "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@", "iconPath=@TargetDir@/resources/eurocontrol.ico", "description=Eurocontrol Developer Tool");
    }
}
```

Below there is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>Eurocontrol Developer Tool</Name>
    <Version>0.11.0</Version>
    <Title>Eurocontrol Developer Tool </Title>
    <Publisher>Honeywell Inc.</Publisher>
    <StartMenuDir>Eurocontrol Developer Tool</StartMenuDir>
    <TargetDir>@ApplicationsDirX86@/Eurocontrol Developer Tool</TargetDir>
    <InstallActionColumnVisible>true</InstallActionColumnVisible>
</Installer>
```

I run also the Installer changing from `@TargetDir@/EurocontrolGui.exe`, to `@TargetDir@\EurocontrolGui.exe`, (the same for `StartMenuDir`). In this case no error was thrown and the shortcut was created although the reference was invalid.

In this case when I run Installer.exe -v from command line, I'm able to see that the path for my application is changed from

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Eurocontrol Developer Tool/EurocontrolGui.exe
```

to

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Eurocontrol Developer ToolEurocontrolGui.exe
```

It looks that the path are malformed during the add Operation.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if QtInstaller gave trouble over forward slashes, but if you want to use backslashes, I believe you have to escape them first, so instead of `@TargetDir@\EurocontrolGui.exe`, it should be `@TargetDir@\\EurocontrolGui.exe`

Below is what I'm using, which works fine. Note that I actually forgot to replace one of the '/' with '\\', but it still works.

```
Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    component.createOperations();
    if (systemInfo.productType === "windows") {
        component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@\\app.exe", "@StartMenuDir@/app.lnk","iconPath=@TargetDir@\\icon.ico");
    }
}
```